# Line break in caption of wrapfigure

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I use the wrapfigure package for placing images in my text at the right side.

Now my problem is, that my image is really small and my caption is larger then the image.
Instead of a line break at the end of the line it adds the chars below each other.
This looks like the following:

[image: Error on wrapfigure package]

So is it possible to add a line break after "Abbildung 4.3:" with the content of \caption?

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{2,76cm}
\includegraphics[]{./bilder/mockup-endtimeError}
\caption{Error Start- Endzeit}
\label{mockup-endtime-error}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

BR & Thanks,
mybecks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package to format the way the captions are displayed. Yo can also use the `ragged2e` package to set your caption as ragged right to avoid bad hyphenations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2\\#3}
\captionsetup[wrapfigure]{name=Figure, justification=RaggedRight, format=myformat}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{2,76cm}
\rule{3cm}{5cm}
\caption{Error Start- Endzeit}
\label{mockup-endtime-error}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

For such small images, I would recommend you use `Fig.` rather than the full `Figure` or the equivalent in German. For more details see the caption manual Section 4.1 Further examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the caption text *separate* from the actual `\caption`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{50mm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=40mm]{example-image}
  \caption[Lorem ipsum]{\unskip}

  Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

`\unskip` removes the space between the usual caption label and text, while the optional argument ensure the proper content makes its way into the LoF.